# Calculated percentage in Delphi DBGrid

Tags: delphi, ms-access, dbgrid, tadotable

I'm maintaining a Delphi application since a few days.
The customer wants to add a percentage column to a DBGrid, now showing a "Quantity" column. Of course the percentage would be the 
Row quantity / Total Quantity * 100

I cannot modify the underlying TADOTable since it is used elsewhere in the code, but I tried to add a calculated field to the TADOTable - but is seems the calculated field cannot have a value based on an aggregate value (i.e. sum of quantity).

I succeeded in adding an empty column to the DBGrid, but is there any way to populate the % values in each row ?

Comment: What database type (MS Sql Server, MySql, etc) are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS Access. No, unfortunately no stored procedures possible....

Comment: I'm thinking about switching from a data-bound Grid to a no-data-bound Grid, since it is meant only for data visualization - no editing

Comment: Just for reference, I ended up using another grid component (TLMDGrid from LMD Innovative) which does not need an underlying dataset and every cell content can be addressed with the syntax thisGrid.Cells[col, row] := value;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is straightforward to do, but you need to be careful how you do it.

Leaving the gui aspect aside for a moment, what you want to do is to add a calculated
column to your TAdoDataSet and initialise it in its `OnCalcFields` event.  However,
what you **DON'T** want to do is to calculate the `TotalQuantity` in that event.
because a) the `OnCalcFields` event will be called for each row in the dataset
AND b) doing anything inside the `OnCalcFields` event which moves the dataset's cursor
- like traversing the dataset as suggested in another answer - will recursively
call the `OnCalcFields` event.

The way to avoid this recursion problem, and to avoid doing any more work than is necessary, is to only calculate the TotalQuantity when
the table is first opened and anytime its value could change, that is, when a row
is edited, inserted or deleted, and then save the result in a field of your form
or datamodule.  There are two main ways you could do this calculation:  1) using a TAdoQuery
to execute Sql like "SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM MyTable" or 2) using **a second instance**
of TAdoDataSet opened on your table.  Preferably this second instance should not have any gui
controls connected to it, so it can be traversed as quickly as possible without
having to use `DisableControls` and `EnableControls`.

To add the Percentage field to your AdoDataSet, double click it to pop up the Fields Editor, right-click in it and select `New field`.  Make sure you set its `Type` to `Calculated`.

Once you have your `GetTotalQuantity` procedure set up, you need to set event handlers to call it
from your AdoDataSet's BeforeOpen, BeforeInsert, BeforeEdit and AfterDelete events.

Then in your `OnCalcFields` event, calculate and assign the value of your Percentage calculated
to it.

The code required to do all this is pretty trivial, something like

```
procedure TForm1.GetTotalQuantity;
begin
  //  AdoQuery1 contains Sql to obtain the sum of the AdoDataSet's
  if AdoQuery1.Active then
    AdoQuery1.Close;
  AdoQuery1.Open;
  try
    TotalQuantity := AdoQuery1.Fields[0].AsFloat;  //  TotalQuantity is a field of your for, (or datamodule)
  finally
    AdoQuery1.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Or

```
procedure TForm1.GetTotalQuantity;
begin
  //  Note: AdoDataSet2 is a second instance of TAdoDataSet set up to access the same
  //  db table as the one connected to the OP's DBGrid
  if AdoDataSet2.Active then
    AdoDataSet2.Close;
  AdoDataSet2.Open;
  try
    TotalQuantity := 0;
    while not AdoDataSet2.Eof do begin
      TotalQuantity :=  TotalQuantity + AdoDataSet2Quantity.AsFloat; // AdoDataSet2.Quantity.AsFloat;
      AdoDataSet2.Next;
    end;
  finally
    AdoDataSet2.Close;
  end;
end;
```

OnCalcFields event:

```
procedure TForm1.AdoDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet : TDataSet);
begin
  if TotalQuantity > 0 then
    AdoDataSet1Percentage.AsFloat := AdoDataSet1Quantity.AsFloat / Total Quantity * 100;
end;
```

Once you've added your Percentage calculated field to your AdoDataSet and set up the OnCalcFields event for the dataset, your DBGrid will be happy to display it, just like any other field of the dataset.

Comment: Oops!  I made a minor correction to the second version of GetTotalQuantity.

Comment: I noticed you retracted your acceptance & upvote of my answer.  Have you had a problem with it?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried calculating the percentage in the OnCalcFields event? Not 100% sure about the following but this example might help you:

```
procedure TClass.DataSetCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  Bookmark: String;
  TotalQuantity: Double;
begin
    // Save current position
    Bookmark := Dataset.Bookmark;

    // Calculate the total quantity in a while loop through the dataset:
    Dataset.First;
    while not Dataset.Eof do
    begin
      TotalQuantity := TotalQuantity + Dataset.FieldByName('QUANTITY').AsFloat;
      Dataset.Next;
    end;

    // Load current position
    Dataset.Bookmark := Bookmark;

    // Calculate the percentage:
    if TotalQuantity > 0 then
    begin
      Dataset.FieldByName('PERCENTAGE').AsFloat := Dataset.FieldByName('QUANTITY').AsFloat / TotalQuantity * 100;
    end
    else
    begin
      Dataset.FieldByName('PERCENTAGE').AsFloat := 0;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Also, have you considered the effect on performance of this way of doing it?

Comment: @MartynA yeah that would surely be an issue, but it was just the quickest solution that came into my mind.. there is definitely a better way to get the total quantity. I just wanted to show OP an example of the OnCalcFields event.